# Continuous operator on C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$$T:C_{\mathbb{R}}[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

Our functional is defined by $T(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$. We have to show that this operator is continuous.

I have an answer but it looks really easy, too easy I would say.

We can see that our function $f(x)$ is continuous on the compact set, so it it uniformly continuous and this function is bounded by some constant $M$.
So we can write it:

$$|T(f)| = \left |\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx\right | \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx \leq \int_0^1 M \, dx = M$$

Our functional is bounded. Hence this implies that functional is continuous, it is the end of the exercise. Am I right?

Comment: It is really easy but you need to put one more thought in it. You need an estimate $|T(f)|\leq C\|f\|_\infty$ for some $C>0$ and all $f\in C_\mathbb R[0,1]$. Where is your $\|f\|_\infty$-part?

Comment: My $\left || f \right ||$ can be equal M? Or not? And then I have that $C=1$.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct, I would probably rather say that $M$ can be chosen as $\|f\|_\infty$ in the above argument but this is what you meant, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $\|f\|_\infty$ instead of $M$ (I'm assuming that this is the norm used in the space $C[0,1]$), the proof is much clearer.